# Entity Framework an error while trying to connect to SQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, entity-framework-6

I am learning about Entity Framework and I was trying to create and setup the tables, which went well but when I had to create them (with update-database) I got this error:

```
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

I am using phpmyadmin.

Here is my code in Data-Context

```
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ranked> Rankeds { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Round> Rounds { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=myServer;Uid=myDB;Database=myDB;Pwd=myPassword;");
        }
```

I have only changed the data inside the string but the reason I am confused is because I was using this db (its from my university) for an year but I used only queries and the Persistence Data Layer to edit information. I have never tried the Entity Framework but I doubt that the problem is in the db. I guess I am doing something wrong which I cannot figure it out.

Comment: please remove your mysql tag as this question belongs to SQL Server. Tag SQL Server here.

Comment: Please check whether your credentials for connectign to SQL server are correct